# Print docs in PDF format in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have made an application in Yii. Now as per my application requirement I have to make them print in PDF format. I searched over Yii docs but did not got any docs about converting file into printable PDF format. So any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: What exactly do you need to convert to PDF? Page output? Other files?

Comment: ... and I see a lot of usefull stuff when Googling `yii generate PDF`, take a look whether your question isn't already answered there

Comment: Yes I want to print the output PDF

Comment: This can become a pretty complicated task. Having the user create a PDF on *their* end is out of the question? (For example, they could install http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFCreator and print any web page from their browser to PDF format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into WkHtmlToPdf:
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

It uses Webkit's rendering engine to make PDFs from HTML / CSS. It's the best library out there that I've found and I've done a bunch of research.

**Edit:**
Mike on the Yii forum has already built an [OO wrapper for WkHtmlToPdf](http://mikehaertl.github.com/phpwkhtmltopdf/) and just released [a Yii extension for it](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdfable/).

Comment: Just updated my answer with some updated tools I've run across since. They're getting even easier / cooler :-)

Comment: And Mike just released a new Yii extension as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used MPDF for a project. It allows you to convert HTML output into PDF format. If you are looking for something simple this might be what you are looking for. Personally, I find it easier to work with HTML/CSS for layout than PDF boxes. I am not sure just how well it scales with complex layouts, though.

Yii also supports using Zend modules. You can use Zend_Pdf if you so choose.

See [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration) documentation page on how to integrate third-party libraries with your Yii code.

Either way, as has already been mentioned, there are tons of PDF libraries available for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for php libraries to do that. Link to one of them - http://www.tcpdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success using fpdf - http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not part of Yii. You can try TCPDF, though. http://www.tcpdf.org/

TCPDF lets you parses your HTML output to PDF document. The PDF document can be output in your server or to the user as a direct download.

Answer (score 0):

Hers the extension to create PDF files. 
 [Yii2-PDF](https://github.com/robregonm/yii2-pdf)