# how to print data in pdf format yii

Tags: pdf, yii

in yii 1.1,I want to print list of data displayed in table into pdf format .I have no idea about this.I am in need of help.

My view code:

```
 <?php  echo CHtml::link('Print Envelop','marketingEmail/pdfPrint', array('class'=>'btn','target'=>'_blank'));  ?>


<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'search-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
 ));
?>
```

```
<table class="bluetable" id="myDemoTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="24"><b>Mail Listing</b></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b>S.N.</b></td>
        <td width="300"><b>Company</b></td>
        <td width="300"><b>Follow up By</b></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php 
    $this->endWidget();

?>
```

Comment: Here you can find some answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433665/print-docs-in-pdf-format-in-yii?rq=1 There's site that allows you to transform site to pdf without downloading libary: http://pdfcrowd.com/

Comment: I'm using this ready extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/

Comment: I tried to use mpdf extension . on using $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf(); there is error saying "Class mpdf does not exist ".

Comment: @Ramlamsal on [yiiframework.com/extension/pdf](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/#hh1) mPDF is a requirement, so you need to download and import the library in "protected/vendors"

Comment: i had used library of mPDF in directory as protected/vendors and there was error: "Class mpdf does not exist"